# Tell Google spreadsheet to finish all calculation before responding the spreadsheet API request

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I three things:
-A Google spreadsheet
-A script attached with the spreadsheet for making my custom formula
-A Android app that uses the google sheet API to fetch data on this spreadsheet

Everything is working fine, my only issue is that the Custom formula are not being calculated before the request is sent to my android app what I get is plenty of: loading...

How can I tell the system to finish those calculations before sending back any http request?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Utilities.sleep() to add a delay and use SpreadsheetApp.flush() to apply all the pending changes to the sheet.